# Drawing Young Tabloids in proper way

Tags: tikz-pgf, tables, diagrams, ytableau

I am trying to get tabloid looks like this
[image]

But no idea how to get something look like it.
All I can get is something look like[image]

by using \ytableausetup.

Comment: Since you have some responses below that seem to answer your question, please consider marking one of them as ‘Accepted’ by clicking on the tickmark below their vote count (see [How do you accept an answer?](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1852)). This shows which answer helped you most, and it assigns reputation points to the author of the answer (and to you!). It's part of [this site's idea to identify good questions and answers through upvotes and acceptance of answers](http://tex.stackexchange.com/about).

Answer (score 2):

If you want the numerals in math font, you need to delimit the argument to `\fbox` as, for example, `\fbox{$2~~3~~4$}`.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[usestackEOL]{stackengine}
\begin{document}
\[
\setstackgap{L}{\dimexpr\baselineskip+2\fboxrule}
 t_1 = \Centerstack[l]{\fbox{2~~3~~4}\\\fbox{1}},\qquad
 t_2 = \Centerstack[l]{\fbox{1~~3~~4}\\\fbox{2}},\qquad
 t_3 = \Centerstack[l]{\fbox{1~~2~~4}\\\fbox{2}},\qquad
 t_4 = \Centerstack[l]{\fbox{1~~2~~3}\\\fbox{4}}
\]
\end{document}
```

[image]